# Select item from list and send it back to server using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of items. I want to select them by clicking. Selected item will be sent to server. At a time only one item can be selected. So, for this I need a variable where I can store the item. Please no jQuery. I am looking for simple Javascript AngularJS. Here is my html. After selecting one item, it will automatically go to another list, which I kept in ng-if=false. Suppose, I click on item1 then it will show the list of list1, list2 and list3. Now, let's select list2. Now item1 and list2 will both go to server.

```html
<div ng-if="true"class="items">
  <ul ng-if="true">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="false">
    <li>list1</li>
    <li>list2</li>
    <li>list3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my fiddle, if I select one date then it should list of dates, which is given ng-if='false'
fiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/abhijitloco/k6jso1u3/

Comment: Where this items and list come from? Is it hardcoded in HTML or maybe ngRepeat?

Comment: Coming from ng-repeat.

Comment: So I suggest that you add real HTML code then.

Comment: Yes, wait 1 mint. I am creating fiddle.

Comment: Hi, this is fiddle. There you will find that dates are showing. Also, there is a time slot which is given ng-if=false. After clicking on one date, it should show time list next. Now, after selecting time, date and time will both go to server. Please have a look :- http://jsfiddle.net/abhijitloco/k6jso1u3/

Comment: Hi, I have given fiddle link. Have you checked?

Comment: Please update your question with the fiddle. This way it will be easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

Look

```js
function AppController($scope) {
  $scope.selectedItem = [];
  $scope.clickItem = function(item) {
    $scope.selectedItem.push(item);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="AppController">
  {{selectedItem}}
  <div class="items">
    <ul ng-if="true">
      <li ng-click="clickItem('Item1');">Item1</li>
      <li ng-click="clickItem('Item2');">Item2</li>
      <li ng-click="clickItem('Item3');">Item3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="obj in selectedItem">
       <li>{{obj}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="items">
  <ul ng-if="!selectedItem" ng-model="selectedItem">
    <li ng-click="selectedItem = item1">Item1</li>
    <li ng-click="selectedItem = item2">Item2</li>
    <li ng-click="selectedItem = item3">Item3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="selectedItem" ng-model="selectedList">
    <li ng-click="selectedList = list1">list1</li>
    <li ng-click="selectedList = list2">list2</li>
    <li ng-click="selectedList = list3">list3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You have selected item in **selectedItem** model and selected list in **selectedList** model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that yours lists and items are dynamic I would propose something like the following:

constroller:

```
$scope.lists = [list1, list2, list2...]
$scope.items = [item1, item2, item3...]

$scope.selectItem = function(index){
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[index];

};

$scope.sentToServer = function(index){
  $scope.lists[index].push($scope.selectedItem);
  //send $scope.lists[index] and $scope.selectedItem;
};
```

view:

```
<div ng-if="true" class="items">
  <ul ng-if="true">
    <li ng-click="selectItem($index)" ng-repeat="item in items>{{item}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="selectedItem">
    <li ng-click="sendToServer($index)" ng-repeat="lists in lists>{{'list' + $index}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As, items and lists are coming from ng-repeat. So, should I leave $scope.lists = [ ] and
$scope.items = [ ] as blank array?

Comment: No!. Your ng-repeats are based on either objects or arrays which hold the data shown in the iterations. So with empty arrays you will not see any <li> markup.
Where is the data coming from you see in the ng-repeat iterations?

Comment: Hi, this is fiddle. It is a date-time picker. There you will find that dates are showing. Also, there is a time slot which is given ng-if=false. After clicking on one date, it should show time list next. Now, after selecting time, date and time will both go to server. Please have a look :- jsfiddle.net/abhijitloco/k6jso1u3

Comment: So you should use the `datevalues` and `timevalues` lists. The described systematic (scope functions and index values) shown in my answer should still be valid

Comment: No, I won't. If you really want to learn angularjs you should get familiar with the basic concepts of the framework. Don't expect the stackoverflow community to do your work.

Comment: I am not understanding what should I put in $scope.lists = [ ] and $scope.items = [ ]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="true"class="items">
     <ul ng-repeat='entry in list1'>
        <li ng-click='clickMe(entry.name)'>{{entry.name}}</li>
     </ul>
     <ul ng-repeat='entry1 in list2' ng-if="secondList">
        <li ng-click='sendToserver(entry1.name)'>{{entry1.name}}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

contorller.js

```
$scope.optionsSelected = {};
$scope.clickMe = function(text){
     $scope.optionsSelected['first'] = text;
     $scope.secondList = true;  // show second list
// you can initialize second list here OR reset values before it is sent to sever

}

$scope.sendToserver = function(text){
     $scope.optionsSelected['second'] =text;
     $scope.textSelected = $scope.optionsSelected;
// $scope.textSelected contains both options you just selected.
}
```

Comment: But, whenever I am clicking on item, next list is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with couple of ngClick and ngIf directives. For example:

```
$scope.showType = 1;
$scope.selected = {};

$scope.selectDate = function(date) {
    $scope.showType = 2;
    $scope.selected.date = date;
};

$scope.selectTime = function(time) {
    $scope.selected.time = time;
    $http.post('date/selected', $scope.selected); // post wherever you need
};
```

where in HTML you would have

```
<ul class="datepicker text-center" ng-if="showType === 1">
    <li ng-click="selectDate(date)" ng-repeat="date in dateValues">{{date | date:'EEE dd'}}</li>
</ul>
<ul class="datepicker text-center" ng-if="showType == 2">
    <li ng-click="selectTime(time)" ng-repeat="time in timeValues">{{time}}</li>
</ul>
```

And here is your code updated:

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/SjxbyfboJlkLnOeDBhdn?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. In server, I am sending selected date and time both. which part is holding date and time both?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks.